# Kinect content missing on the Turtlebot

Tags: navigation, kinect, turtlebot, openni-kinect, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm coming back to Turtlebot after a couple of months on other things. Wow, things are looking great! It's really coming together.

I'm having a curious problem and I hope someone can provide some guidance. This started out when I started running through the gmapping tutorial. Teleoperation was working fine, but I wasn't seeing anything coming up in rviz. So I tried subscribing to the image topics, using image_view, etc. Still no video. So now I've backed up and am trying to resolve this problem.

After figuring out that the stuff in kinect.launch wasn't referenced in turtlebot.launch and is now brought up separately (I am lazy and created a custom launch file that includes kinect.launch), I got the openni_kinect topics to show up. The Kinect is powered on, it shows up in lsusb, etc., and the laser is merrily red. Here's my rostopic list:

```
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/disparity
/camera/depth/image
/camera/depth/image/compressed
/camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image/theora
/camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/points
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_color
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_mono
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora
/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/points
/cloud_throttled
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/diagnostics_agg
/imu/data
/imu/raw
/joint_states
/kinect_laser/parameter_descriptions
/kinect_laser/parameter_updates
/kinect_laser_narrow/parameter_descriptions
/kinect_laser_narrow/parameter_updates
/map
/map_metadata
/narrow_scan
/odom
/openni_camera/parameter_descriptions
/openni_camera/parameter_updates
/openni_manager/bond
/robot_pose_ekf/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/slam_gmapping/entropy
/tf
/turtlebot/app_list
/turtlebot/application/app_status
/turtlebot_node/parameter_descriptions
/turtlebot_node/parameter_updates
/turtlebot_node/sensor_state
```

... except nothing seems to be actually publishing to the camera topics. For example, a "rostopic hz /camera/rgb/image_color" doesn't give me anything, but a rostopic hz /odom gives me the rate info I expect. None of the other /camera topics get anything, either; I get no response from /camera/depth/image,

Sooo, back to rviz. If I add a display in rviz (Camera, topic /camera/rgb/image_color), I get a Status: warning message that says "No CameraInfo received on [/camera/rgb/camera_info]. Topic may not exist. But it does exist (see above), it's just that nothing is happening on it. if I rostopic echo or rostopic hz on /camera/rgb/camera_info, I don't see anything.

I tried running the gmapping stuff, which launches the kinect stuff. Again, I see the topics, but nothing is being published on them.
Now I back up. Skip all of the Turtlebot stuff, and just roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch. Again, all of the topics show up and the laser goes red on the Kinect, but nothing is being published on any of the /camera topics, including camera_info.

But wait! If I turtlebot_bringup with the kinect.launch referenced, and then go into another ssh session and run roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch, I get a lot of messages like this, but it suddenly starts to work: the rostopic hz calls start showing the rates, and the image shows up in rviz, albeit at a pretty low frame rate and with a few hundred milliseconds lag:

```
[ WARN] [1322104870.100115748]: [image_transport] Topics '/camera/depth/image_rect_raw' and '/camera/depth/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      0
    CameraInfo messages received: 300
    Synchronized pairs:           0
[ WARN] [1322104880.100552875]: [image_transport] Topics '/camera/depth/image_rect_raw' and '/camera/depth/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      0
    CameraInfo messages received: 328
    Synchronized pairs:           0
[ WARN] [1322104890.101621893]: [image_transport] Topics '/camera/depth/image_rect_raw' and '/camera/depth/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      0
    CameraInfo messages received: 450
    Synchronized pairs:           0
```

I've tried this on two different machines (an Asus netbook and an HP notebook) and with two different Kinect sensors. Both computers are running Oneiric and Electric, with the Turtlebot software installed with apt-get. I haven't tried the Turtlebot build itself, but I can if that's what is recommended.

I found [this discussion](http://answers.ros.org/question/2386/openni_kinect-dosent-publish-anything-in-the), which isn't specifically Turtlebot-related, but it makes me wonder if the change to Electric has caused some issues.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12074/kinect-content-missing-on-the-turtlebot/) by [Alaina](https://answers.ros.org/users/767/alaina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2011-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might have a look at [this answer by Patrick Mihelich](http://answers.ros.org/question/2993/registered-depth-only-works-sometimes-with#4768) to another similar kinect related question. I dont know if the new binaries are already out, but i doubt it. Maybe you could try to build the most recent version from source like suggested and give feedback to Patrick if it helped.

I was fighting with this issue for weeks with natty and electric and for me a clean reinstall and switch vom 32 to 64 bit helped a lot, but didnt solve the problem completely.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alaina](https://answers.ros.org/users/767/alaina/) on 2011-11-24**:
That's great, Ben. If I rosinstall/rosmake the latest, it works fine. Looks like we can expect a permanent fix soon.